# acts_as_follower get record blocked or unblocked

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Is there a way to get a bool if the record exists in database, even if it is set to blocked true or false?

Something like:

```
user.following_blocked?(book)
```

Regards!

Comment: can you give a better example?

Comment: I mean, user.following?(book) returns true if there is a record and blocked is set to false, what i need is something to return if that record exists even if blocked is true.